# Difference between Minitest::Spec and ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

what is the difference between using `Minitest::Spec` and `ActiveSupport::TestCase` in my `test_helper` in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This project aims to enable MiniTest within the Rails TestCase
>   classes. Your test will continue to inherit from
>   `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, which will now support the spec DSL.
>   [Minitest on Github](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails)

This means you don't have to use `Minitest::Spec` and can simply use `ActiveSupport::TestCase` all the time to get some convention in your code.

Edit: When you don't use minitest-rails gem you have to `register_spec_type`

```
class ControllerSpec < MiniTest::Spec                                                                                                                                                
end                                                                                                                                                                                  

# Functional tests = describe ***Controller                                                                                                                                          
MiniTest::Spec.register_spec_type( /Controller$/, ControllerSpec )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually used anything besides rspec, but according to their public APIs, [ActiveSupport::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html) only supports testing if an error was raised, while [Minitest::Spec](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Spec.html) has a bit more support for testing things other than succesful DB queries.